# How to comprehend the hooks of Substrate? Such as `on_initialize`, `on_finialize` and `offchain_worker`

Tags: offchain-worker

I want to use hooks for some  business  logic, but I'm not very familiar with the usage of `on_initialize`, `on_finialize` and `offchain_worker`. Can all of them modify the on chain storage? If yes, what is the order?

I guess so

1. a node import a block
2. execute `offchain_worker`
3. execute `on_initialize`
4. execute all the extrinsics in the block
5. execute `on_finalize`

Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

The order is the following:

1. A node imports/start building a block:

- `on_initialize` is called for all Pallets in the runtime.
- All extrinsics are executed/applied.
- `on_finalize` is called for all Pallets in the runtime.

2. Import/Block building is finished:

- `offchain_worker` is called.

Any changes the offchain worker is doing, cannot be seen by the on chain logic. Any change to the on chain state must happen inside a block. The offchain worker has its own offchain storage for read + write and can also read the on chain storage. The onchain logic can use the offchain indexing functionality to store special data that is only readable by offchain workers and is not part of the on chain state.

Comment: Looking at the Substrate source code, I don't understand how these hooks like offchain_worker() are called. I see the hooks in pallet/expand/hooks.rs but I fail to see code that actually makes the call to offchain_worker(). What am I missing? –

Comment: It is called here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/59a74b18df148b9b4b460ba1d0322948f96d04d0/client/offchain/src/lib.rs#L166-L175

Answer (score 1):

Offchain workers modify storage by submitting a txn. And the order of execution is Offchain worker does  not interfere with other txn and they are run on block importation.

The other hooks run on block formation, So on_initialize is when a block is prepared and initialized and then transactions ( so if offchain worker submitted a txn to the pool the txn will be executed).

But offchain workers don't follow that order, because it is made to not interfere with the normal txn execution flow.